# tutorial to use zf-doctrine cli tool by https://github.com/beberlei/zf-doctrine?

Tags: doctrine, zend-framework

I'm new to zend and I've tried a few apps using it and I watched all most all the zendcast videos. and i come to know about the zf-doctrine command line tool which does the doctrine zend bind for us. but the problem is when i follow thought the tutorial in the line it says to replace

> resources.frontcontroller.controllerDirectory

with

```
resources.frontcontroller.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

my application starts giving the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Exception'
>   with message 'Invalid controller specified

as I read in the google this is due to unspecified error controller(please correct me if I'm wrong). so I was wondering, is there a step by step tutorial to guide me how to use this tool? and how does modules work?

Also it does not mention what libraries I should use and where can I download them, i used with Zend and doctrine orm library

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my `config/application.ini`, I have the following:

```
doctrine.models_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/models"
```